# Using SQL Login Credentials that are different from the Run As Service Account

Tags: tableau-api

Wondering if anyone has successfully connected to MS SQL Server using SQL Login credentials, that are different from the Tableau Run As service account?

I've tried reviewing the [Tableau documentation on impersonation](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/impers.htm), however their link for "[Embedded SQL Credentials](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/impers_SQL.htm)" takes you to a 404.

Also, any ideas why impersonation is only supported for Live connections and not data extracts?
I'd love to use Hyper extracts for this specific data set, but I am limited to a set user/pwd.

Answer (score 2):

Extracts are an in-memory feature specific to Tableau. Impersonation is database specific to MS Sql Server. Because impersonation only works at the database level, and it relies on knowing who is logged in at the time the query runs, it only works for a live connection.

If impersonation is not a mandatory requirement for you, there are ways to implement row-level security on extracts that don't rely on impersonation. This allows you to have one database account (can be separate from the Run As service account) and relies on the Tableau Server username, rather than the impersonating database account. I use this technique with financial, HR, and sales data to limit who sees what, and still gain the performance of an extract. Version 2018.3 (presently in beta) has additional features to make row-level security on extracts even better.

Comment: could you elaborate on how you were able to connect to SQL Server using an account other than the Run As? If I could get this working, I would be set.

Comment: The connection to Sql Server is completely dependent on the credentials provided in the data source, which you set when you publish the workbook or data source to Server. The Run As user is a mechanism for Server to run in the OS with the correct privileges without needing a user to be physically logged in at all times. The two users are completely independent of each other; maybe I'm not understanding your question though.